# How to switch geth synced to ETH mainnet, to ETHPOW fork mainnet upon launch without having to sync chain from scratch?

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum

I have a geth node synced to the ETH mainnet, and once there is a POW hardfork, such as ETHPOW, I would like to think it is possible to change the geth settings, so that it begins to sync to the new ETHPOW network, while maintaining the entire history of data that was previously synced to the ETH mainnet, and going forward syncing the new ETHPOW fork's chain data.

I am unsure if this is actually possible, or if the ETHPOW network must be synced from scratch, or if it is as simple as changing some settings in geth, such as the following API AND CONSOLE OPTIONS, HTTP-RPC server listening port (default: 8545):

- --http.port [NEW_PORT_NUM]

Or the following NETWORKING OPTIONS, Network listening port (default: 30303):

- --port [NEW_PORT_NUM]

Other possible options that I see that may need changing are
ETHEREUM OPTIONS, TOML configuration file:

- --config value

The goal is to prevent having to sync to the new network and building the database from scratch when the official details are released, so syncing to the new chain happens with only needing to sync a few blocks, all without corrupting the previously downloaded chains info.

Any information on which command line options to be set or changed, if possible, and why it would work, would be most appreciated. If it's not possible, please propose other possible solutions. An explanation of why it isn't possible would also be welcomed